# Does Intermittent fasting increase growth hormone secretion without negating strength gain benefits?

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training

I have heard many claims, and done some reading, but I am not qualified by any means to determine the truth of the matter:

> **Question:** Will Intermittent fasting, increase growth hormone secretion significantly, and is this benefit not mitigated by some other consequence of fasting?

This is in regard to wanting to gain strength and or size. Does intermittent fasting actually increase GH and not cause negative effects that cancel this benefit? Is it worth doing for strength training?

If what I am reading is true, I have no idea why all bodybuilders and power lifters wouldn't be intermittent fasting. (This is how I feel about all wild claims like this. If they are really as effective as stated, why aren't they widely used)